# MySQL Query - how to remove everything before "/" including next "/"

Tags: mysql, sql

In my DB column I have this:

```
2017/05/imagename.png
```

and I need just:

```
imagename.png
```

I was trying something like this:

```
  UPDATE wp_postmeta 
  SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, left(meta_value, INSTR(meta_value, '/')-1),'') 
  WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_wp_attached_file'
```

But after using this query, I get this result:

```
05/imagename.png
```

Any idea how could I fix my query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like mysql.  If so, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
update wp_postmeta
    set meta_value = substring_index(meta_value, '/', -1)
    where meta_key LIKE '_wp_attached_file';
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll read more about substring_index to understand it :)